# How to get ProcessStartInfo with arguments from a java process By using C#?

Tags: c#, java, process, arguments

I am trying to get a java Process object by using C#.
The thing is i have several java Processes running on my computer.

Following is the way i chose to get Processes:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("java");
foreach(Process proc in processes){
    //I need a filter here to get the correct process.
}
```

The java Process is also controlled by my C# program as below:

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.FileName = javahome + "\\bin\\java.exe";
 startInfo.Arguments = "-jar Example.jar port=88888";
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "\\testFolder";
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 Process proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
 proc.Start();
```

What i want is go through the array of Process to check which one has the same Arguments with the Process object that i started in another program.
But the problem is when i did like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(proc.StartInfo.Arguments);
```

I found there is nothing in it, even i know it is the process that i started in another program. This confused me a lot.

Does anyone know this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it that way. When you start a process keep the handler for that process in a dictionary where the value is the process arguments, that's the only way I see for you to archive that.

```
        Dictionary<IntPtr, string> processArguments = new Dictionary<IntPtr,string>();

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = javahome + "\\bin\\java.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "-jar Example.jar port=88888";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "\\testFolder";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
        proc.Start();

        processArguments.Add(proc.Handle, javahome + "\\bin\\java.exe");

....

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("java");
        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            var arguments = processArguments.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(proc.Handle)).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
```

Comment: My problem is they are running in two different programs. One for startup, one for kill. Is there a way to do such an operation?

Comment: Oh I see. Well you can use Memory-Mapped files to share data (the dictionary) between the two aplpications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this by using LINQ as below :

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("java");
var fileteredProcess = from pro in processes
                        where (pro.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory == "workingDIR") &&
                        (pro.StartInfo.Arguments == "Arguments")
                        select pro;

foreach (var proc in fileteredProcess)
{

}
```

Comment: pro.StartInfo is empty (may be for non-admin users only).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using WMI:

```
Process[] processes;
Process selectedProc = null;
int selectedProcId = 0;

//  http://wutils.com/wmi/
//  using System.Management;
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process "
                                  + "WHERE Name = 'java.exe'");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
        // access properties of the WMI object
        Console.WriteLine("CommandLine : {0}", m["CommandLine"]);
        Console.WriteLine("ProcessId : {0}", m["ProcessId"]);

        if (m["CommandLine"].ToString().Contains("my pattern"))
        {
            selectedProcId = int.Parse(m["ProcessId"].ToString());
            selectedProc = Process.GetProcessById(selectedProcId);
            break;
        }
}

if (selectedProc != null)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Proc title {0}", selectedProc.MainWindowTitle);
}
```